# fake geolocation with scrapy crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website which serves different page depending upon the geolocation of the IP sending the request. I am using an amazon EC2 located in US(which means it serves up a page meant for US) but I want the page that will be served in India. Does scrapy provide a way to work around this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If the site you are scraping does IP based detection, your only option is going to be to change your IP somehow. This means either using a different server (I don't believe EC2 operates in India) or proxying your server requests. Perhaps you can find an Indian proxy service?